# Best Final Cut Pro Export Quality Options

Tags: video, export, finalcut

I'm importing `MP4` videos into `Final Cut Pro v10.3.4` and making a simple movie.  I make proxy media for quick scrubbing and wish to export the best quality that I can find.  I need the best quality, and the `MP4` file provides great quality to begin with.  But I can't find anything similar.  I'm exporting various grades in the `settings` panel on export, and I have over 5 GB for a file that is exported all the way down to 56 MB, given the options I have available.  But nothing comes close to the source files (the `MP4`'s).

How can I make this export the best quality?  Doesn't look like I have the incoming quality as an option for export.  My options right now are:

```
Source (Proxy media, which is bad)
Apple ProRes 4444 XQ
Apple ProRes 4444
Apple ProRes 422 HQ
Apple ProRes 422
Apple ProRes 422 LT
Apple ProRes 422 Proxy
H.264
Uncompressed 8-bit 4:2:2
Uncompressed 10-bit 4:2:2

AVC-Intra Class 50
AVC-Intra Class 100
AVC Intra Class 200
DVCPRO HD
HDV 18 Mbps
XDCAM EX 35 Mbps
XDCAM HD44 50 Mbps
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple ProRes 4444 XQ is a super high quality format, but it's probably overkill. This would be used for the final online edit. It depends on your use case. If this is going to a color studio, then Apple ProRes 4444 XQ is the way to go.

If you're publishing to the web, compress down to H.264. No big deal.

The quality will be limited by your source files in either case.

Comment: Well that's just it.  All of them are worse than the incoming `MP4` files.  I exported to 4444 XQ and it's worse.  I'm confused how this can be.  Again, it's about obtaining the highest quality, not saving space.

Comment: some things to potentially explore: 1. what codec and bitrate is underneath the MP4 wrapper  2. how are you viewing the output quality? i.e. what player/why does it seem worse? Unless you have a crazy beefy system, it may be difficult to do realtime playback with Apple ProRes 4444XQ.

Comment: 1.  Through ffmpeg from `mkv` files.  They are crystal clear in QT7 Player.  I'm seeing some fuzziness on aspects made on this security footage (Date, time, etc.) as well as a street sign that's absolutely clear in the `mp4`. At this point it's easier to cut and paste in QT7 Player, then add the Intro generator in `FCP`.

Comment: Cut and paste makes sense. If you're generating fuzziness, one possibility is your converting framerates which can potentially blend frames. If that is the problem, making sure to match frame rates could resolve. Good luck!

Comment: Ah good point.  Source `mp4's` are 15 fps.  So I just exported at 30 fps (2x) and she's still blurry.  Should I match these?

Comment: That would be the first thing I would try. I think there is also a setting for drop-frame vs. non-dropframe which needs to match as well. (i.e. 30fps is not the same as 29.997)

Comment: I'm sure those would demonstrate a conflict.  So I'll stick to 30.  I have to start recapturing as of now.

Comment: Good luck. I recommend doing a small piece as a proof of concept before recapturing the whole enchilida. could save time.

Comment: Hah exactly what I'm doing.  I'm capturing security footage so reduction and quality are both issues.

Comment: So a 30 fps `mp4` goes into `FCP` and proxy media made.  Exported on its own, highest quality, 623 MB, and horrible video quality.  I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that you didn't try the **Apple Devices 4K...**, which will export a video with high quality and small file size, namely heavily compressed video. Just give it a try.